# VB.Net - How to search in a listbox bounded by dictionary?

Tags: vb.net

So I have a listbox that is bounded by ID (key), and Name (Value). This is the method I used to bind the dictionary to the listbox:

```
listCustomer.DataSource = Nothing
listCustomer.Items.Clear()

Dim listCustomerSource As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
While (dr.Read())
    listCustomerSource.Add(dr.GetString(0), dr.GetString(1))
End While

listCustomer.DataSource = New BindingSource(listCustomerSource, Nothing)
listCustomer.DisplayMember = "Value"
listCustomer.ValueMember = "Key"
```

This is the method I have in textbox_textchange:

```
Private Sub searchList(ByVal textbox As TextBox, ByVal listbox As ListBox)
    Dim hits = From item In listbox.Items.Cast(Of String)() Where (item.IndexOf(textbox.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    If hits.Any Then
        listbox.SelectedItem = hits.First()
    Else
        listbox.ClearSelected()
    End If
End Sub
```

I have tried it in a listbox with just a text (unbound) and it works just fine, but if I use it in a listbox with bounded dictionary, it gets an error 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.String]' to type 'System.String'.' upon typing in the textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when you bind a datasource the items are no more simple strings but instances of the datasource. When you bind a Dictionary every item in your ListBox is an instance of a KeyValuePair class. The values set on the DisplayMember or the ValueMember are used only for display purpose by the ListBox, your items are all *KeyValuePair(Of String, String)*

So, you just need to change you line that search your match to

```
Dim hits = From item In l.Items.Cast(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))() 
           Where (item.Value.IndexOf(x, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got no error with this but I'm not able to search the values, I have tried it with key and it works. I wonder why. :/ EDIT: item.Value.Equals should be item.Value.IndexOf, it works now! thanks.